# Get uneven and unrelated rows merged together in the result with null for missing values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have 2 tables:

```
Table A:
Name1
Name2
Name3
```

Table B:

```
USA
UK
FRANCE
CANADA
INDIA
GERMANY
```

Expected Output

[image]

Just like a report for all

Comment: Not much to go on here. Please indicate the DB you're using in your question. One shouldn't have to look at the tags to see what the question involves. Also, have you tried any queries? If so, what were they? Have you searched the internet and SO for an answer? If so, please indicate that you did some footwork before posting a question,

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option; read comments within code.

```
SQL> with
  2  -- sample data
  3  ta (name) as
  4    (select 'name1' from dual union all
  5     select 'name2' from dual union all
  6     select 'name3' from dual
  7    ),
  8  tb (country) as
  9    (select 'USA'     from dual union all
 10     select 'UK'      from dual union all
 11     select 'France'  from dual union all
 12     select 'Canada'  from dual union all
 13     select 'India'   from dual union all
 14     select 'Germany' from dual
 15    ),
 16  -- create *something* (RN) to use to join those tables
 17  tarn as
 18    (select name,
 19            row_number() over (order by name) rn
 20     from ta
 21    ),
 22  tbrn as
 23    (select country,
 24            row_number() over (order by country) rn
 25     from tb
 26    )
 27  -- and finally ...
 28  select a.name,
 29         b.country
 30  from tarn a full outer join tbrn b on a.rn = b.rn;

NAME  COUNTRY
----- -------
name1 Canada
name2 France
name3 Germany
      India
      UK
      USA

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: What I gave was a sample data. The actual data is dynamic, and can change. And I want a report sql query, the result of which I can copy into a spreadsheet and send over email.So selecting each value from dual is not a possibility. Any alternative?

Comment: I see you aren't familiar with the WITH factoring clause a.k.a. CTE (Common Table Expression). If you posted proper test case, including CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO statements, I wouldn't have to create one on my own. That's what the first 15 lines I posted do - create sample data. Query you need begins at line #17 (preceded by the WITH keyword. In other words, you wouldn't select *anything* from DUAL, you already have those values in your tables. So ... educate yourself, don't judge too soon.